# Angular, get throws Access-Control-Allow-Origin but still returns the answer, how can i get that?

Tags: angular, get, cors

I am trying to call a `get` service using this `HttpClient` class. It  throws the usual  CORS problem error but when I look at the "response" field, it is returning the answer information I wanted to obtain (as can be seen in the image):

[image: error but correct answer]

What I am doing inside the classes is:

```
//HttpclientmanagerService class
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class HttpclientmanagerService {

  constructor(
            private http: HttpClient
          ) { }

  login(username): Observable<any>{
      let url = 'http://localhost:9666/loginUserServlet?user='+username.toString();
      return this.http.get(url);
  }

}
```

and the caller class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpclientmanagerService} from "../services/httpUtils/httpclientmanager.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private httpmngr: HttpclientmanagerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  login(){
    this.httpmngr.login('usertest').subscribe(
                      result => {

                          if(result.code != 200){
                            console.log('result data (200):\n'+result);
                          }else{
                            console.log('result data:\n'+result.data);
                          }
                        },
                      error => {
                          console.log(<any>error);
                        }
                    )
  }

}
```

any advice to help find the answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you control the server that sends the response, just sent the CORS headers along with your response

Comment: If you can see the response in devtools, that indicates the browser is getting the response. But the fact the browser is getting the response doesn’t mean the browser will allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response. For cross-origin requests, unless the response includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header — which the response shown in the header does not — then browsers will block your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the response.

Comment: @user184994 , sideshowbarker    you both were right, but  i have no access to the server which  is responding that. That is why i was trying to avoid it. your answer was key to stop trying to get the info from browser.

What i did is to use a  server i own as a pivot to consume that service and expose my own service and it is being consumed from my application